# Compare the Elements of List and creating a [key value Pairs or Maps] based on logic in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, scala-collections

I have a list with the following data. I have to compare the elements of the list and create a map with specified condition.  The SFTP.csv should map to /dev/sftp/SFTP_schema.json same with other elements.

```
List[String] = List(
  "/dev/sftp/SFTP.csv" , 
  "/dev/sftp/test_schema.json" , 
  "/dev/sftp/SFTP_schema.json",
  "/dev/sftp/test.csv"
)
```

I have a large set what is the fastest way to do it?

Comment: @Andrey Tyukin, Is there anything wrong with my question?

Comment: I just indented it a little bit, so that it's not necessary to scroll the long string horizontally. This way, it's easier to recognize the patterns in the ending. If you are asking about the downvote: I didn't downvote it. Probably the one who downvoted did it because there is no solution attempt.

Comment: Now I'm kind-of embarrassed: if I knew that this horrible function name would end up in a question title on StackOverflow, I'd certainly choose a shorter name^^ Why on Earth did you put it in the title!?? It's just a really bad function name that I've just come up with three minutes ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you essentially want to invert a `map.flatMap{ case (k, v) => List(k, v)) }`? That looks like fun... How about this?:

```
val input = List(
  "/dev/sftp/SFTP.csv" , 
  "/dev/sftp/test_schema.json" , 
  "/dev/sftp/SFTP_schema.json",
  "/dev/sftp/test.csv"
)

val res = input.
  groupBy(s => s.
    split("/").
    last.
    replaceAll("\\.csv","").
    replaceAll("_schema\\.json","")
  ).
  map { 
    case (k, v1 :: v2 :: Nil) => 
      if (v1.endsWith("csv")) (v1, v2)
      else (v2, v1)
    case sthElse => throw new Error(
      "Invalid combination of csv & schema.json: " + sthElse
    )
  }

println(res)
```

Produces:

```
// Map(
//   /dev/sftp/SFTP.csv -> /dev/sftp/SFTP_schema.json, 
//   /dev/sftp/test.csv -> /dev/sftp/test_schema.json
// )
```

As method:

```
def invertFlatMapToUnionKeyValue(input: List[String]): Map[String, String] = {
  input.
    groupBy(s => s.split("/").last.
      replaceAll("\\.csv","").
      replaceAll("_schema\\.json",""
    )).
    map { 
      case (k, v1 :: v2 :: Nil) => 
        if (v1.endsWith("csv")) (v1, v2)
        else (v2, v1)
      case sthElse => throw new Error(
        "Invalid combination of csv & schema.json: " + sthElse
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: It working perfectly fine, When i am working on console it returns Map[String,String] , But when i placed in function it is returning a tuple of (String,String). Where am i going wrong?

Comment: I don't know. It works just as fine if you wrap it into a method. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can partition a list into 2, based on a predicate:

```
val (csvs, jsons) = input.partition (n => n.endsWith (".csv"))
// csvs: List[String] = List(/dev/sftp/SFTP.csv, /dev/sftp/test.csv)
// jsons: List[String] = List(/dev/sftp/test_schema.json, /dev/sftp/SFTP_schema.json)
```

Then just iterate over the names, stripping off .csv and _schema.json:

```
for (c <- csvs;
  j <- jsons;
  if (c.substring (0, c.length - 4) == j.substring (0, j.length - 12))) yield 
    (c, j)
```

to combine the matches.

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that there is an entry for json schema always for a csv, one approach could be to partition and zip the lists after sorting.

```
val (csvs, jsons) = input.partition (n => n.endsWith (".csv"))
csvs.sorted.zip(jsonSchemas.sorted)
```